# How can I estimate an overall intercept in a cumulative link mixed model?

Tags: logistic-regression, threshold, intercept

I am testing a `cumulative` link mixed model, and I want to estimate an overall intercept for the model.

The outcome of interest has 4 categories, so the model has 3 `logits` each with a unique intercept (threshold coefficient).

The model is tested in R with the ordinal package using the `clmm` function. I included a random intercept, a random slope, and a `cross-level` interaction.

The model looks like this:

```
comp.model.fit<-clmm(competence_ordinal~competence.state.lag1+ tantrum_dur.state.lag1+NEUROw1.c+tantrum_dur.state.lag1:NEUROw1.c+ (1+tantrum_dur.state.lag1|ID_nummer), data, Hess = TRUE, na.action = na.exclude)
```

Results of the fitted model showed that the cross-level interaction is significant. So, I would like to find out the region of significance of the simple slope, that defines the specific values of the moderator (NEUROw1.c) at which the slope of the regression of the outcome (competence_ordinal) on the focal predictor (tantrum_dur.state.lag1) transitions from non-significance to significance.

To compute a test for simple slopes I need an estimate for the intercept, however, in this type of model an overall intercept is not identified alongside the threshold coefficients.

Therefore, my question is how can I estimate an overall intercept?
Is there a way to constrain the first threshold to zero to be able to estimate the intercept?